# Lodash complicated key value replace

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using lodash/_, and I'd like to generate the following output from the input JSON.

Any input on how to achieve this, would be great.

Input:

```
{
    "hex": "#EFDECD",
    "name": "Almond",
    "rgb": "(239, 222, 205)"
},
{
    "hex": "#CD9575",
    "name": "Antique Brass",
    "rgb": "(205, 149, 117)"
},
```

Desired Output:

```
{
  Almond: '#EFDECD',
  Antique Brass: '#CD9575',
  ...
};
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use `Array.prototype.reduce` method for this:

```
let data = [{
  "hex": "#EFDECD",
  "name": "Almond",
  "rgb": "(239, 222, 205)"
},
{
  "hex": "#CD9575",
  "name": "Antique Brass",
  "rgb": "(205, 149, 117)"
}];

let newData = data.reduce((result, elem) => {
    result[elem.name] = elem.hex
    return result;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use plain Javascript to achieve that (`Array.prototype.reduce`):

```js
const collection = [{
    hex: '#EFDECD',
    name: 'Almond',
    rgb: '(239, 222, 205)',
  },
  {
    hex: '#CD9575',
    name: 'Antique Brass',
    rgb: '(205, 149, 117)',
  },
]

const sorted = collection.reduce((result, el) => {
  result[el.name] = el.hex
  return result
}, {})
console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just incase you really do want to lodash, the reduce function is indeed available there too:

```js
const collection = [{
    hex: '#EFDECD',
    name: 'Almond',
    rgb: '(239, 222, 205)',
  },
  {
    hex: '#CD9575',
    name: 'Antique Brass',
    rgb: '(205, 149, 117)',
  },
]

const sorted = _.reduce(collection, (result, el) => {
    result[el.name] = el.hex
    return result
}, {})

console.log(sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```